# Quiz system score php

Tags: php

I was working on a quiz page where I need some assistance to count the marks.

> 1 Correct Answer = 1 mark
>
> 3 Wrong Answers = -1 mark
>
> Unanswered Answer = 0 mark

I have code to count all answers as correct, wrong, or unanswered.

```
$response = mysql_query("select qus_id, qus_cans from question where qus_id IN ($order) ORDER BY FIELD(qus_id,$order)", $kpsctuts->connect) or die(mysql_error());   
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
    if($result['qus_cans']==$_POST[$result['qus_id']])
    {
        $right_answer++;
    }
    else if($_POST[$result['qus_id']]==5)
    {
        $unanswered++;
    }
    else
    {
        $wrong_answer++;
    }
    // Enter Code Here
}
```

Outputting the marks:

```
<p>Total no. of right answers : <span class="answer"><?php echo $right_answer;?></span></p>
<p>Total no. of wrong answers : <span class="answer"><?php echo $wrong_answer;?></span></p>
<p>Total no. of Unanswered Questions : <span class="answer"><?php echo $unanswered;?></span></p>
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: i want the score with 2 decimal point

Comment: How do you count 'the score' then? How would you get 2 decimal points from integers as you're only summing integers?

Comment: give sample example how you want it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should define a variable `$marks` equal to 0. Then if `$right_answer` has any value, store it in `$marks` directly because you have to give +1 mark for right answer. Then similarly check if any wrong answer is present or not.

Your code continues with the following piece of code:

```
$marks = 0;
if($right_answer) $marks = $right_answer;
if($wrong_answer) $marks = $marks - $wrong_answer/3;
$score = number_format((float)$marks,2,'.',''); //Only two decimal places
echo "The score is: ".$score;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `bcadd()`, or `number_format()`

```
<?php 
     $total = $right_answer - ($wrong_answer/3);
     echo bcadd($total,0,2);
?>
```